Adjacency Matrix of Connected Bipartite Graph
If I have a connected bipartite graph with 2 and 3 nodes respectively represented by the adjacency matrix
$$
A(2,3) =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
as far as I understand, the adjacency matrix of the graph with all paths of length $k$ in $A(2, 3)$ can be calculated by multiplying $A(2, 3)$ by itself $k$ times. Therefore for $k = 2$ it should be
$$
A^2(2,3) =
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm supposed to determine the entries of $A^k(n,m)$ based on $n$, $m$ and $k$. So far, I've realized that I have to differentiate between the cases

$k = 2p + 1$ (odd)
$k = 2p$ (even)

For the first case I realized that there are no paths of length $k$ between two vertices that are in the same connected component. Therefore, the entries for $A^{2p + 1}(n, m)$ in the first $n$ rows and $n$ columns and the last $m$ rows and $m$ columns must be $0$. All other values must be greater than zero.
Similarly, for the second case, there are no paths of length $k$ between two vertices that are not in the same connected component. Therefore the first $n$ rows and last $m$ columns and last $m$ rows and first $n$ columns must be $0$. Again all other values must be greater than zero.
The task states "Determine the entries of $A^k(n, m)$ as a function of $n$, $m$, and $k$." so therefore I'm not sure if what I have so far is enough and if not how I would describe the value of the remaining entries.

Welcome to Math SE. It is expected here that posts be written using MathJax. Since this is your first post here, I have gone ahead and edited it for you. But in future, please typeset the mathematical copy in your posts appropriately.

Oh, and by the way, the adjective you wanted is bipartite. Your misspelling, *bipartide, reminds one of the unrelated noun apartheid.

For a matrix-focused approach, it's probably best to write the even case as $A^n=(A^2)^p$. Since $A^2$ is block-diagonal, it's then more straightforward to exponentiate. (This also assists in the odd case, which can be written as $(A^2)^p A$.)

Your graph is not merely bipartite but in fact complete bipartite, which makes the computation more tractable.

Let $G$ be a complete biparite graph with bipartition $ \{V_{1},V_{2}\}$ with $n$ vertices in $V_{1}$ and $m$ vertices in $V_2$.
consider a walk of odd length $k=2p+1$.
while constructing the walk, we have $m$ choices for the next edge whenever we are at a vertex in $V_2$ and $n$ choices for the next edge whenever we are in edge in $V_1$, except for the last edge, for which there is only $1$ choice.
We visit   both $V_1$ and $V_2$ exactly $p$ times before the last edge. Hence, there are $m^pn^p$ such walks. (Note that this number does not depend on whether we are starting at $V_1$ to $V_2$).
For walks of even length $k=2p$, we apply the same logic, except we visit our starting part $p-1$ times and the other part $p$ times before the last edge. Hence, there are $m^pn^{p-1}$ such walks from $V_1$ to $V_2$ and $m^{p-1}n^p$ such walks from $V_2$ to $V_1$.
This should help you to construct $A^k(n,m)$.
